# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk: How do you customize a Ruby AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby, amazon-beanstalk

[The following article](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customami.html) explains detailed how to create a custom **Tomcat based** AMI for Beanstalk. The key is running the following commands before creating your AMI:

```
sudo -s
cd /etc/init.d
./httpd start
./tomcat7 start
```

However I didn't find any documentation what the configuration must look like on the new **Ruby based** Beanstalk servers.

Does anyone already have experiance with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Ruby based Elastic Beanstalk containers do not require any special configuration prior to deploying your Rack based web application.  You may find you need to customize the environment.

If you need to manage the packages installed on your environment, you should use the .ebextensions configuration that is deployed with your web application.  You can learn more about this [here](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/10/customize-elastic-beanstalk-using-configuration-files.html) and [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html).

If you need to install Ruby gems that your web application relies on, you should include a Gemfile with your web application.  These gems will be installed when deploying your application.